# sed command for text selection with starting and stopping phrase

Tags: sed

I know the typical sed editing statements, such as

`sed "s/substitutethis/withthis/g" file`

However, when I searched for how to extract lines between two phrases, I found this:

`sed -n "/startphrase/,/stopphrase/p" file`

**Could someone explain, please?** The man page does not help me.
I know that `-n` suppresses echoing of output. Why do they use `-n` and `p`? Leaving out both does not work. What does the comma stand for?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-Programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
"/startphrase/,/stopphrase/p"
```

means "from the line containing `startphrase` to the line containing `stopphrase`, print".

There are many sed tutorials that talk about "range of lines".